# Ploting the rejection,acceptance and indecision in R

Tags: r, data-science, hypothesis-test

I am trying to plot the rejection, acceptance and indecision curves according to this:

if psup < α then reject H0,
• if α < pinf then do not reject (accept) H0,
• otherwise (ie, if pinf ≤ α ≤  psup ) then suspend the decision and, for example, demand more observations to make a well‐based decision.

I want to integrate all 3 curves in one plot, where in the x we have the M values(values from -1 to 1 used to calculate the pinf and psup) and in the y the p values.I also have a list with the pinf and the psup.

The code I have is this:

```
data<-data.frame(M=M_values,p_min=pmin,p_max=pmax)
alpha<-0.05

# Acceptance condition
data$aceitacao <- ifelse(data$p_min > alpha, data$p_min, data$p_max)
data$aceitacao <- as.numeric(data$aceitacao)
#data$aceitacao[is.nan(data$aceitacao)] <- NA

# Rejection condition
data$rejeicao <- ifelse(data$p_max < alpha, data$p_max, data$p_min)
data$rejeicao <- as.numeric(data$rejeicao)
#data$rejeicao[is.nan(data$rejeicao)] <- NA

# Indecision condition
data$indecisao <- ifelse(data$p_min <= alpha & data$p_max >= alpha, (data$p_min + data$p_max) / 2, 0)
data$indecisao <- as.numeric(data$indecisao)
#data$indecisao[is.nan(data$indecisao)] <- NA

# Plot
ggplot(data, aes(x = M)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = aceitacao), colour = "green", linetype = "solid", size = 1, na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_line(aes(y = rejeicao), colour = "red", linetype = "solid", size = 1, na.rm = TRUE) +
  #geom_line(aes(y = indecisao), colour = "blue", linetype = "solid", size = 1, na.rm = TRUE) +
  labs(x = "M", y = "p", colour = "Curvas") +
  theme_minimal()
```

The plot I am obtaining is this:

[image]

the rejection(red) is okay and the indecision(blue) too but the acceptance(green) is wrong.

I want a plot like this:

[image]